# Horizontal page inside vertical page issue in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have created `Two pages` of horizontal pageview.
 - First page is API value load vertical pageview
 - Second page is detail view

Problem is vertical pageview scrolling to two or three pages. then horizontal pageview scroll to second page. then again horizontal pageview scroll first position, vertical pageview position automatically refreshed issue. how to solve??

```
class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  MyPageView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  _MyPageViewState createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}
class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  List<News> _list = List<News>();
  PageController _pageController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  Future<List<News>> fetchNews() async {
    //Use your own api key if this stops working
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=f8c15ba22b0b4ec08dd9f84c3480d709');
    Map map = json.decode(response.body);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(map['articles'][0]);
    //print(responseJson['articles'][1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < map['articles'].length; i++) {
      if (map['articles'][i]['author'] != null) {
        _list.add(News.fromJson(map['articles'][i]));
      }
    }
    return _list;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchNews(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        //return new Text('loading...');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return _buildPageViewContainer(context, snapshot);
        }
      },
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: <Widget>[
            futureBuilder,
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text("Hiii", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24.0),)
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildPageViewContainer(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _pageController,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return _buildPage(context, position);
              },
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: _list.length,
            ),
          ),
        ]
    );
  }
  Widget _buildPage(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
        elevation: 10,
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Image.network(
                '${_list[index].urlToImage}',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '${_list[index].title}',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  '${_list[index].description}',
                  softWrap: true,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                )),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class News {
  Source source;
  String author;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  String urlToImage;
  String publishedAt;

  News({this.source, this.author, this.title, this.description, this.url, this.urlToImage, this.publishedAt});

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return new News(
      //  source: (json['source'] as List)
      //   ?.map((e) =>
      //       e == null ? null : new Source.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
      //   ?.toList(),
        source: new Source.fromJson(json['source']),
        author: json['author'],
        title: json['title'],
        description: json['description'],
        url: json['url'],
        urlToImage: json['urlToImage'],
        publishedAt: json['publishedAt']
    );

  }
}

class Source{
  String name;
  String id;

  Source({this.name, this.id});

  factory Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return new Source(name: json['name'],
        id: json['id']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      <String, dynamic>{'name': name, 'id': id};
}
```

Comment: can you post your code to understand it properly, and describe your problem precisely

Comment: i like selected vertical position value show to second page. and again first page horizontal scroll to vetical view don't call api

Comment: you have returned the same page in every index, if you want different Widgets at different pages, prepare a List of widgets and store in that and return that list widgets in the PageViewBuilder